# Access invoice header data (invoice_id) from invoice line tree

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

Dears!

I need to access the sales invoice header data (namely the field `invoice_id`) to default another value for a field (`analytics_id`) in the invoice line table tree view.

I wrote the following code to determine the default value for the field `analytics_id` and implemented it in a custom class which inherits `account.invoice.line`:

```
class my_account_invoice_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "account.invoice.line"

    def _default_analytics_id(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}

        invoice_id = context.get('invoice_id', False)
        if invoice_id:
            inv_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice').browse(cr, uid, invoice_id, context=context)
            plan = inv_obj.plan_id
            return plan

        return False

    _defaults = {
        'analytics_id': _default_analytics_id,
        }

my_account_invoice_line()
```

To my surprise, the `invoice_id` field is not available in the context (`context.get('invoice_id', False)` always returns `False`) although the invoice header *is* already created and *has* an id. I am sure, it must be available somehow - just can't think of any way on how to do it.

Can you please put me into the right direction?

Any help is gratefully appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks,

finally I made it - and documenting my results here, hoping it may helps anyone else to solve this kind of problem.

The invoice id (or any other field from invoice header) needs to be explicitly passed via the `context` attribute in the corresponding XML file. Hence I modified the `context` attribute of the field `invoice_line` in an inherited form as follows:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_custom_account_invoice_form_inherited">
    <field name="name">account.invoice.form</field>
    <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='invoice_line']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="context">{'type': type, 'custom_field_id': custom_field_id}</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Remark: `context="{'type': type}"` is the standard value in OpenERP 7 (see file `/addons/account/account_invoice_view.xml`).

As soon as this is done, the value for `custom_field_id` from the invoice header data is available in the invoice line and you can use it for your purposes:

```
class my_account_invoice_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "account.invoice.line"

    def _default_analytics_id(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        custom_id = context.get('custom_field_id', False)
        if custom_id:
            # ...your code to do something with custom_id goes here...
            return True # or whatever suits your needs to be used as default
        return False

    _defaults = {
        'analytics_id': _default_analytics_id,
        }

my_account_invoice_line()
```

Regards